# Как в .Net принять информацию об платы материнской имени?

Tags: .net

Знаю примеры с System.Management и подключением к WMI.
Но из всех примеров находимых в гугле, удаётся доставать только MotherBoard SN (серийный номер).
Нужно прям по нормальному, доставать имя платы материнской (и желательно вообще без "тракторизма", в виде подключений к WMI).